# Where are the latest mono release notes

Tags: mono

I am trying to find release notes for mono versions 2.10.11 and 2.10.12 but cant seem to find them.   The latest I can find is 2.10.9.   http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10.9

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mono updated to version 3.

See latest mono release notes:

http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0#New_in_Mono_3.0

Answer (score 0):

Actual Mono version for MAC OS X, Windows and openSUSE is 3.2:

http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.2